# Lock Word document after macro executed using PIA

Tags: c#, ms-word, pia

I am using the Office PIA to integrate an application into Word.

There are multiple word documents which run a macro when you open them. My goal is to lock the current document, but **after** the macro has run. Is there a way to do this? Thought something like this should work, but there is no such event like "MacroExecuted" or something else:

```
public void OpenDocument(string path)
{
    var app = new Application();
    app.Documents.Open(path);
    app.ActiveDocument.MacroExecuted += LockDocumentEvent;
    app.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I just checked vba-internal and there it looks like `app.Documents.Open(path);` would only return after the associated code was executed. Did you actually have an issue with still running macro when `Open` returned?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, after long search:

The important method is contained in the Document Object.

```
app.ActiveDocument.RunAutoMacro(WdAutoMacros.wdAutoOpen);
```

WdAutoMacros enumeration contains different values which indicates which macro schould be executed. For me it was

> WdAutoMacros.wdAutoNew

and

> WdAutoMacros.wdAutoOpen

Now the macro is executed after opening the document from Office SDK.